# Rails 500 error overwrites my headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails application with the cors being set on before_filter:

```
def cors
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-AUTH-TOKEN, X-API-VERSION, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
end

before_filter :cors
```

And this works just fine. Then if an error is thrown on the route, the headers get overwritten.

```
def index
  object.undefined_method() // undefined method `undefined_method'
end
```

Response headers:

```
Keep-Alive
Content-Length →16399
Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8
Date →Thu, 08 May 2014 18:51:20 GMT
Server →WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2013-11-22)
X-Request-Id →6ace3d4e-4367-452c-a924-c4c490f207de
X-Runtime →0.130761
```

Even though the before_filter runs, those headers are not there. Although the 500 error shouldn't exist, I would like for the front-end developers to be able to give me a more descriptive error than "I did this and the CORS didn't work." I would expect the CORS to be in the result.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you would have to add the headers to the 500.html file in your public folder. Not sure on that though...

Comment: @n_i_c_k I'm not talking about the <head> tag of an html file, but the headers on the http response.

Comment: Yes, I understand. you can use `<meta http-equiv=` in your <head> to simulate response headers. Alternately, you could tell you rails app to handle your error pages instead of using 500.html, then your before filters should work.

Comment: That won't work for json responses, which is my problem. Is there a way to override the 500 response?

Comment: I´ve been experiencing the same problem for a while and still didn't find a proper solution. Did you maybe find one?

Answer (score 1):

By default Rails uses [Rack Middleware](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1f85e1c9f34c7b0bdc1bddad5f914d61cb2a5435/railties/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb#L113) for handling errors. This middleware [totally skips](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/71c7fd101324046995d8f7e51e78475c0e37ec1a/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/public_exceptions.rb#L19) any headers from requests. Possible solution - use your own handler for error pages, many good ideas are described [here](https://mattbrictson.com/dynamic-rails-error-pages)